# xampp and network

Tags: networking, localhost, xampp

I have build a site working on my localhost using xampp on windows7.
Now, I my colleagues want to access and use that site in our small office.

I tried to access the site using IP address of my own system. but some urls are redirecting to  localhost... and there is no localhost at other computers in my office.

the problem is the site is built with CodeIgniter framework so it containes a constant `site_url` which it's value is `http://localhost/site`.

I know that I need a server (or domain controller) and I have to put my site on that server so all other computers would access to it.

I can't figure out how to implement what is need without a computer used as server in our office.

Can I use a virtual machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change that site_url from "http://localhost/site" to "http://your.ip.add.ress/site" (use your ip address). It should work then (if this is the only place where the url is hardcoded in your app).